# Keyboard overlays on SeachView , not able to move the searchbar above keyboard by default

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the below code in layout. I have the `SearchView` at the bottom of `RelativeLayout`

I want to bring the searchview on top of keyboard when it gets focus

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:foregroundGravity="top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="530dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried the below code but it doesnt work as expected

Isnt Android suppose do it by default?

### MainActivity

```cs
searchview.FocusChange += Searchview_FocusChange;
```

---

```cs
 private void Searchview_FocusChange(object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.HasFocus)
      {
                searchview.Parent.BringChildToFront(searchview);
                searchview.BringToFront();

      }

}
```

### Before Focus

[image]

### After Focus

[image: Overlayed keyboard]

How do I fix this? I tried some options mentioned in other posts with no luck.

- WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize
- android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" on recyclerview

As a work around I added below code, but I do not feel comfortable with this

```cs
searchview.Click += Searchview_Click;
```

---

```cs
private void Searchview_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (sender is SearchView searchview)
   {
       searchview.Parent.BringChildToFront(searchview);
       searchview.BringToFront();

       searchview.SetY(searchview.GetY() - 100);
       searchview.SetY(searchview.GetY() + 100);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the **RelativeLayout** in a **ScrollView**

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">


   <RelativeLayout
   //...

</ScrollView>
```

And set the **windowSoftInputMode** in **Manifest.xml**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

Comment: Wrapping `RelativeLayout` in `ScrollView` fixed it, no need of setting `windowsoftInputMode` Thanks